# 3rd party tool to minimize the manual effort - SharePoint 2010?

Tags: permissions, powershell, tools

We would like to setup a tool to help us on the below listed activities and dont expect any additional features, the tool should be cost effective as we have 2wfes with less than 4k users.

- Manage Permission Inheritance
- Find unique permission items
- Copy user permissions
- Transfer user permissions
- Delete Permissions
- Clean up old user accounts
- Discover Permissions against the Farm, Web Application and Site Collection
- List and List Item broken permission inheritance report
- Permission reports
- Permission Audit(optional)

Our consideration is

- Deliverpoint
- Quest Site Administrator for SharePoint
- Axceler Controlpoint

and its license details..

Comment: Please rephrase this to get a more directed answer. All of these products do what you want, some give additional benefits. As it is, this is overly opinion based.

Comment: have updated the question, please have a look...

Comment: @PirateEric, request you to unhold this as I have updated the question as per your suggestion, please let me know if still you feel something is missing..I'm really depend on the experts suggestions.

Comment: Are you asking for a commercial tool or a open source tool? Any answer referencing a commercial tool will get moderator attention since commercial tools are off topic for this site. This question is on the fine line between open and closed.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to go with free tools or with Powershell however we could not find any of such..and started looking for the paid once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My contribution to the community

```
########################################################################
# Generated On: 12/12/2013 3:45 PM
# Generated By: Karthikeyan Vijayakumar
########################################################################

#Generated check Web Permission
function Get-SPUserEffectivePermissions(
    [string]$user, 
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]$InputObject) {

    begin {
        # Determine the URL to the securable object being evaluated
        $parentWeb = $null
    }
    process {
        $so = $InputObject

        if ($so -eq $null) { $so = $_ }

        if ($so -isnot [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]) {
            throw "A valid SPWeb, SPList, or SPListItem must be provided."
        }

        if ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]) {
            $parentWeb = $so
        } elseif ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]) {
            $parentWeb = $so.ParentWeb
        } elseif ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]) {
            $parentWeb = $so.ParentList.ParentWeb
        }

        if($parentWeb -ne $null) {
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({
            $spUser = $parentWeb.EnsureUser($user);

            if($spUser -ne $null) {

                # Get the users group details.
                $spUserGroups = $spUser.Groups;
                $spUserGroups |% {
                    $webGroup = $_;
                    $webGroupName = $webGroup.Name;
                    $webGroupRole = $webGroup.Roles |% {$_.Name + ","} | out-string
                    $newRow = @( $parentWeb.Url, $webGroupName , $webGroupRole )
                    $dataGridView1.Rows.Add($newRow)     
                }

                # Get the users permission details.
                $permInfo = $spUser.Roles                

                # Iterate through them
                if ($permInfo.Count -gt 0) {
                    for($i=0; $i -lt $permInfo.Count; $i++) {
                        $permName = $permInfo[$i].Name
                        $permRoles = "`t"
                        #$permRoles = "Direct"
                        #$permRoles = $permInfo[$i].Type

                        if ($permName -ne "Limited Access") {
                           $newRow = @( $parentWeb.Url, $permRoles , $permName )
                           $dataGridView1.Rows.Add($newRow)
                        }
                        else {
                           checkListPermissions $parentWeb $spUser
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
       });
       }
    }
    end {
        if($parentWeb -ne $null) {
           $parentWeb.Dispose(); 
        }
    }
}

#Generated check List Permission
function checkListPermissions($web, $spUser) {
    begin {
    }
    process {
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({
        $web.Lists |% {
            $spList = $_;
            if($spList.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) {
                $spUserRoles= $spList.RoleAssignments |? {$_.Member -like $spUser.LoginName} 
                    if($spUserRoles -ne $null) {                
                        $spUserRoleBindings = ($spUserRoles | select RoleDefinitionBindings).RoleDefinitionBindings |% {$_.Name + ","} | out-string
                        $newRow = @( ($web.Site.Url + $spList.DefaultViewUrl ), $spList.Title, $spUserRoleBindings )
                        $dataGridView1.Rows.Add($newRow)                      
                    }
            }
        }
        });
    }
    end {
    }
}

#Generated Remove Web Permission
function Remove-SPUserEffectivePermissions(
    [string]$user, 
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]$InputObject) {

    begin {
        # Determine the URL to the securable object being evaluated
        $parentWeb = $null
    }
    process {
        $so = $InputObject
        if ($so -eq $null) { $so = $_ }

        if ($so -isnot [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]) {
            throw "A valid SPWeb, SPList, or SPListItem must be provided."
        }

        if ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]) {
            $parentWeb = $so
        } elseif ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]) {
            $parentWeb = $so.ParentWeb
        } elseif ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]) {
            $parentWeb = $so.ParentList.ParentWeb
        }

        if($parentWeb -ne $null) {
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({
            $spUser = $parentWeb.EnsureUser($user);

            if($spUser -ne $null) {
                $answer= [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Are you sure do you want to remove the permission of - $($spUser.DisplayName)" , "Status" , 4)
                if ($answer -eq "YES" ) {
                    # Get the users group details and remove.
                    $spUserGroups = $spUser.Groups;
                    $spUserGroups |% {
                        $webGroup = $_;
                        $webGroup.RemoveUser($spUser);  
                    }

                    # Remove the user roles.
                    $parentWeb.RoleAssignments.Remove($spUser);
                    $parentWeb.Update();                    
                    #Notify the Administrator
                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("User permission have been removed..!" , "Status");
                }                        
                else {
                    #Notify the Administrator
                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Action has been cancelled by the Administrator..!" , "Status");
                }            
            }
            else {
                #Notify the Administrator
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("User not found..!" , "Status");
            }
       });
       }
    }
    end {
        $dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        if($parentWeb -ne $null) {
           $parentWeb.Dispose(); 
        }
    }
}

#Generated check Web Permission
function Copy-SPUserEffectivePermissions(
    [string]$user, 
    [string]$userTarget,
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]$InputObject) {

    begin {
        # Determine the URL to the securable object being evaluated
        $parentWeb = $null
    }
    process {
        $so = $InputObject
        if ($so -eq $null) { $so = $_ }

        if ($so -isnot [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]) {
            throw "A valid SPWeb, SPList, or SPListItem must be provided."
        }

        if ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]) {
            $parentWeb = $so
        } elseif ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]) {
            $parentWeb = $so.ParentWeb
        } elseif ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]) {
            $parentWeb = $so.ParentList.ParentWeb
        }

        if($parentWeb -ne $null) {
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({
            $spUser = $parentWeb.EnsureUser($user);
            $spUserTarget = $parentWeb.EnsureUser($userTarget);

            #Check if the Target user exists
            if($spUserTarget -ne $null ) {

                #Check if the Source user exists
                if($spUser -ne $null ) {

                    # Get the users group details.
                    $spUserGroups = $spUser.Groups;
                    $spUserGroups |% {
                        $webGroup = $_;
                        $webGroup.AddUser($spUserTarget);
                    }

                    # Get the users permission details.
                    $permInfo = $spUser.Roles

                    # Iterate through them
                    $permInfo |% {
                        $permName = $_.Name;

                        if($permName -ne "Limited Access") {
                            $_.AddUser($spUserTarget);
                        }
                        else {
                            setListPermissions $parentWeb $spUser $spUserTarget
                        }
                    }
                    #Notify the Administrator
                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Permission has been copied..!" , "Status");
                }
                else {
                    #Notify the Administrator
                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Source User does not exist..!" , "Status");
                }            
            }
            else {
                #Notify the Administrator
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Target User does not exist..!" , "Status");            
            }
        });
        }
    }
    end {
        if($parentWeb -ne $null) {
            $parentWeb.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

#Generated check List Permission
function setListPermissions($web, $spUser, $spUserTarget) {
    begin {
    }
    process {
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({
        $web.Lists |% {
            $spList = $_;
            if($spList.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) {
                $spUserRoles= $spList.RoleAssignments |? {$_.Member -like $spUser.LoginName}
                if($spUserRoles -ne $null) {
                    $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($spUserTarget)
                    $spUserRoleBindings = ($spUserRoles | select RoleDefinitionBindings).RoleDefinitionBindings

                    $spUserRoleBindings |% {
                        $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($_)
                        $list.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
                        $list.Update();                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    }
    end {
    }
}

#Generated Form Function
function GenerateForm {
#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$label4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$global:txtTargerUserLoginName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$btnRemovePermision = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnCopyPermission = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$global:dataGridView1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$btnClear = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnGetPermisison = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$global:txtUserLoginName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$global:txtWebURL = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------
#Provide Custom Code for events specified in the Form.
$btnRemovePermision_OnClick= 
{
    Get-SPWeb $txtWebURL.Text | Remove-SPUserEffectivePermissions $txtUserLoginName.Text
}

$btnCopyPermission_OnClick= 
{
    Get-SPWeb $txtWebURL.Text | Copy-SPUserEffectivePermissions $txtUserLoginName.Text $txtTargerUserLoginName.Text
}

$handler_form1_Load= 
{
    $dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3
    $dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
    $dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Web URL"
    $dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Group Name"
    $dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Permission Level"

    $dataGridView1.Columns[0].width = 300
    $dataGridView1.Columns[1].width = 138
    $dataGridView1.Columns[2].width = 260
}

$btnClear_OnClick= 
{
    clearForm
}

$btnGetPermisison_OnClick= 
{
    $dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    Get-SPWeb $txtWebURL.Text | Get-SPUserEffectivePermissions $txtUserLoginName.Text
}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{
    #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 597
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 796
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.Name = "frmSPMgr"
$form1.Text = "SharePoint User Permission Manager"
$form1.add_Load($handler_form1_Load)

$label4.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 218
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 562
$label4.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label4.Name = "label4"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 287
$label4.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$label4.TabIndex = 11
$label4.Text = "This Application is designed by Karthikeyan Vijayakumar @2013."

$form1.Controls.Add($label4)

$txtTargerUserLoginName.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 189
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 101
$txtTargerUserLoginName.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$txtTargerUserLoginName.Name = "txtTargerUserLoginName"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 573
$txtTargerUserLoginName.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$txtTargerUserLoginName.TabIndex = 10

$form1.Controls.Add($txtTargerUserLoginName)

$label3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 30
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 101
$label3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label3.Name = "label3"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 212
$label3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$label3.TabIndex = 9
$label3.Text = "Email Address of Target User"

$form1.Controls.Add($label3)


$btnRemovePermision.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 478
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 139
$btnRemovePermision.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$btnRemovePermision.Name = "btnRemovePermision"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 108
$btnRemovePermision.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$btnRemovePermision.TabIndex = 8
$btnRemovePermision.Text = "Remove Permision"
$btnRemovePermision.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btnRemovePermision.add_Click($btnRemovePermision_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($btnRemovePermision)


$btnCopyPermission.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 372
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 139
$btnCopyPermission.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$btnCopyPermission.Name = "btnCopyPermission"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 99
$btnCopyPermission.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$btnCopyPermission.TabIndex = 7
$btnCopyPermission.Text = "Copy Permission"
$btnCopyPermission.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btnCopyPermission.add_Click($btnCopyPermission_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($btnCopyPermission)

$dataGridView1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 30
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 181
$dataGridView1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 351
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 741
$dataGridView1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$dataGridView1.TabIndex = 6

$form1.Controls.Add($dataGridView1)


$btnClear.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 190
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 139
$btnClear.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$btnClear.Name = "btnClear"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$btnClear.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$btnClear.TabIndex = 5
$btnClear.Text = "Clear"
$btnClear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btnClear.add_Click($btnClear_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($btnClear)


$btnGetPermisison.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 271
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 139
$btnGetPermisison.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$btnGetPermisison.Name = "btnGetPermisison"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 95
$btnGetPermisison.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$btnGetPermisison.TabIndex = 4
$btnGetPermisison.Text = "Get Permision"
$btnGetPermisison.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btnGetPermisison.add_Click($btnGetPermisison_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($btnGetPermisison)

$txtUserLoginName.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 188
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 63
$txtUserLoginName.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$txtUserLoginName.Name = "txtUserLoginName"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 574
$txtUserLoginName.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$txtUserLoginName.TabIndex = 3

$form1.Controls.Add($txtUserLoginName)

$label2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 30
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 63
$label2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label2.Name = "label2"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 152
$label2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$label2.TabIndex = 2
$label2.Text = "Email Address of the User"

$form1.Controls.Add($label2)

$txtWebURL.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 188
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 27
$txtWebURL.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$txtWebURL.Name = "txtWebURL"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 574
$txtWebURL.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$txtWebURL.TabIndex = 1

$form1.Controls.Add($txtWebURL)

$label1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 30
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 30
$label1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label1.Name = "label1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 18
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 131
$label1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$label1.TabIndex = 0
$label1.Text = "Enter the Web URL"

$form1.Controls.Add($label1)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

function clearForm {
    $txtWebURL.Text = "";
    $txtUserLoginName.Text = "";
    $txtTargerUserLoginName.Text = "";
    $dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
}

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using PowerShell with SharePoint - there are tools, code libraries and a good book out there which could cover most of your requirements (& it'll be much cheaper too) :

[Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Command Builder](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/TechNet/en-us/Office/media/WindowsPowerShell/WindowsPowerShellCommandBuilder.html)

[SharePoint Management PowerShell scripts (CodePlex)](http://sharepointpsscripts.codeplex.com/)

[Automating SharePoint 2010 with Windows PowerShell 2.0 (book)](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470939206,miniSiteCd-SYBEX.html)

Comment: There are two other books - PowerShell for SharePoint 2010 How-To:  http://www.amazon.com/PowerShell-SharePoint-2010-How-To-Steven/dp/067233559X PowerShell for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Administrators:   http://www.amazon.com/PowerShell-Microsoft-SharePoint-2010-Administrators/dp/0071747974/ref=pd_sim_b_7